# azure time series insights explorer issues

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

We are started working on integrating Azure Time Series Insights. When we send simple format of payload to TSI we are able to see the data in the TSI ex: { "DeviceID":"dev1","temp":10.4,"pressure":"20.4"}.
We were able to see the data in the explorer(in all explorer) dev1->temp or dev1->pressure and able to plot the data.

But when we are trying to send the packet for in the below format we are unable to get the tagId values under deviceId. We can only see eventData and can plot but when we explore the event data we can actually see the data exists. I am not sure what i am missing here. by the way we are using Gen2(L2) version

[{
"deviceId": "RDevice01",
"timestamp": "2020-25-01A09:25:45:4840",
"series": [{
"tagId": "Axis1",
"value": 0.75
}, {
"tagId": "Axis2",
"value": 0.001
}, {
"tagId": "Axis3",
"value": 0.001
}, {
"tagId": "Axis4",
"value": -4.08319
}, {
"tagId": "Axis5",
"value": -1.93166
}, {
"tagId": "Axis6",
"value": -4.08319
}, {
"tagId": "ErrorAxis1",
"value": "String 0"
}, {
"tagId": "ErrorAxis2",
"value": "String 1"
}, {
"tagId": "ErrorAxis3",
"value": "String 2"
}, {
"tagId": "ErrorAxis4",
"value": "String 3"
}, {
"tagId": "ErrorAxis5",
"value": "String 4"
}, {
"tagId": "ErrorAxis6",
"value": "String 5"
}]
}]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've changed your JSON telemetry payload such that you now have nested JSON and your series are within an array, you'll need to have a TS ID (composite or singular) within the array objects to trigger flattening, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-json-flattening-escaping-rules#example-b

You can re-create a new TSI instance with a composite TS ID of deviceId and tagId, and then that'll work as you expect.